# CopSSH home path discrepancy

Tags: windows, ssh, sftp, copssh

We've got a current system running CopSSH v4, and we're implementing a replacement solution on v7.

One of the issues we've run into is the home path that the user is presented with when they connect to the server via ssh and sftp.

In the current system, when a user connects with either `ssh` or `sftp`, and is in their home directory, the `pwd` command returns `/home/<user>`.

In the new setup:

- with `ssh` it returns `/home/___<user>`
- with `sftp` it returns `/cygdrive/<Windows Drive>/<SubFolders>/<user>`

How do I get the paths to match, and how do I get rid of the spurious underscores from the ssh displayed home.